# Bash how to check if string contains '*'?

Tags: bash, shell

Bash how to check whether a string in bash contains `*`. Since `*` is a special character?

Comment: escape it? after escaping it becomes exactly like any other characters, and checking it is just like checking if the string contains any other characters

Answer (score 2):

```bash
if [[ $string == *"*"* ]]; then echo "string contains asterisk"; fi
```

Within double braces, the `==` operator does *pattern matching*. Quoted parts of a pattern are handled as literal strings.

With a regex, `*` is not special inside a bracket expression, or when quoted:

```bash
if [[ $string =~ [*] ]]; then echo "string contains asterisk"; fi
if [[ $string =~ "*" ]]; then echo "string contains asterisk"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep "\*" filename` if you need to check if a string within a file contains a "*".

As `*` is a special character it is then necessary to use the escape character `\`.

Comment: no need to do that. Just `grep -F '*'`. But that's very expensive if the string is already in a variable